# Vue, i18n and vue-meta how to make integration?

Tags: vuejs2

how to do that when changing the site language, the meta page also changed?

I use 
vue-i18n -  https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/ 
vue-meta -  https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-meta.

App.vue

```
export default {
        name: 'Name',
        metaInfo: {
            title: 'Title', // set a title
            titleTemplate: '%s - title', // %s  required
            htmlAttrs: {
                lang: 'ru',
                amp: undefined // "amp" has no value
            },
            meta: [
                {   'name':'og:title',
                    'content': 'title',
                },
                {   'name':'metatitle',
                    'content': 'title',
                },
                {   'name':'og:description',
                    'content': 'Description',
                },
                {   'name':'description',
                    'content': 'Description',
                }

            ]

        },
        data(){return{ }},
        mounted() {}
```

Comment: We should all change the word "integration" to "friends".

Answer (score 10):

Instead of defining metaInfo as an object, define it as a function and access this as usual.

```
export default { 
   metaInfo () { 
      return { title: this.$t("home.title") } 
   } 
}
```

Et voilà ! :)

Answer (score 0):

or you can use

```
import i18n from '@/locales/i18n'
export default {
metaInfo() {
        return {
            meta: [
                {
                    name: 'title',
                    content: i18n.t('meta.title'),
                },
          ],
        }
    },
}
```

where @/locales/i18n is the path to your locale file, meta tags will change automatically when you switch to another language. I using vue-meta 2.4.0 and vue2