# Use vue-i18n in script

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-i18n

i use vue-i18n. i want to make the title property dynamic based on i18n but i can't use $t in script. (there is a mixin file for title)

**vue file;**

```
  export default {
     name: "SubscriptionList",
     title: "$t('title')"
  }
```

**i18n;**

```
<i18n>
{
    "en":{
        "title" : "Subscriptions",
     },
    "de":{
        "title" : "Abonnements",
     }
}
</i18n>
```

**titleMixin.js**

```
function getTitle (vm) {
    const { title } = vm.$options
    if (title) {
      return typeof title === 'function'
        ? title.call(vm)
        : title
    }
}
export default {
    created () {
      const title = getTitle(this)
      if (title) {
        document.title = title
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: what about `title: this.$t('title')`?

Comment: i tried it but im getting "cannot read property '$t' of undefined" error

Comment: are you using vue meta?

Comment: if you want use this.$t() in title maybe you should use function instead of string
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53915818/vue-i18n-and-vue-meta-how-to-make-them-friends

Comment: what do you mean by *there is a mixin file for title*?

Comment: i added the mixin file content can you check it?

Comment: but it's not used as mixin

Comment: why? there are multiple vue files

Comment: try out `title: (vm)=>vm.$t('title')`